# xsd validation in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, xsd

I am using CodeIgniter, and I want to validate xml with below xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:simpleType name="non_empty_string">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:element name="xml">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="item">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:union memberTypes="non_empty_string xsd:integer"/>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

when I am trying to validate xml against this xsd, **only first member type is getting validated (non_empty_string )**, not the second one, any guess why this is happening. Thank you.

Comment: how you are using the codeigniter's validation for validating it. please post the code

Comment: Though I am using codeignitor but I am not using any speific vlaidation library, I am doing it with php to compare xml with xsd, is their any specific function that I can use to validate xsd with different memberTypes? thanks

Comment: @Nishikant can you include the xml you have tested it against, and the resuits you're getting please? I checked it with xmllint, and it accepts both a single letter and a multi-digit integer (as expected), so at least that confirms your xsd is OK. Tools sometimes don't fully implement the xml schema spec (or are buggy), so that might explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMLReader to validate your XML against  xsd file.
 refer this [link](http://de.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.setschema.php) for more information 
http://de.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.setschema.php